# Style single words inside TextInput widget

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am building a text editor with linguistics functionalities.

I am using the Kivy framework for the first time but I am liking it a lot (it is a middle ground between Tkinter and QT in power-productivity ratio). I was able to build most of what I need already, except this: how can I format individual words/letters inside a TextInput widget?

Simple example: the editor has spell-check abilities (it checks if a word exist in a DB), how can I highlight a word if it does not exist, by changing the color to red, or adding a red background shadow, but only in that single word, the rest of the text continues black?

It is easy to do this to all the text (editing foreground_color property), but from what I read in the documentation the TextInput widget is poor when it comes to manipulating text (I can get cursor info and position, but can't manipulate - TKinter for instance is better in this, it allows using personalized hidden tags and styles).

There is the kivy.core.text.markup widget, that adds BBCODE functionality, but only to labels, can't integrate with TextInput. An interesting thing is the CodeInput widget, but it only works with Pygments, for code syntax highlight, can't use it for target words in a DB in a spell-checker.

Any ideas?

I was thinking on drawing red rectangles under words with Canvas, but I don't know how to get the right position and size, and would need to disable background colors or images in the TextInput for that. Since CodeInput can highlight code syntax I know it is possible, but no idea how since there is no documentation for such a thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since your application is able to extract word from the TextInput's text, and check it against the DB, you can use `select_text(start, end)` and  `selection_color` to highlight the word in error.

[TextInput » select_text(start, end)](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.select_text)

> ```
> select_text(start, end)
> ```
>
> Select a portion of text displayed in this TextInput.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> ```
> start
> ```
>
> Index of textinput.text from where to start selection
>
> ```
> end
> ```
>
> Index of textinput.text till which the selection should be displayed

[TextInput » selection_color](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.selection_color)

> ```
> selection_color
> ```
>
> Current color of the selection, in (r, g, b, a) format.
>
> **Warning**
>
> The color should always have an “alpha” component less than 1 since
>   the selection is drawn after the text.
>
> selection_color is a ListProperty and defaults to [0.1843, 0.6549,
>   0.8313, .5].

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have thought about that too, but I think it would not work in this case: the app spellcheck is in real time, while the user is typing it is always checking each word and showing grammar info on a side box. Using the selection for highlighting words, each time the user writes a new letter or clicks with mouse button on the TextInput, would result in the selection disappearing. I assume the select_text works like Word text editors (f.e.): when someone clicks or writes the selection disappears. If there were a way for the selection to stay forever, yes it would work.

Comment: PS: I could run again the code for selecting and highlighting wrong words each time something is typed, that way it would be always visible. But imagine a document with 100 pages and dozen of wrong words, doing that each time the user writes a new letter must be very slow :/ The best way would do it only once, and it stay on during all the session.